# Should I use jQuery templates even though they're not officially released?

Tags: jquery, templates

I've recently been looking around for Javascript templating solutions.  I'd like to use the official jQuery templates plugin, but it seems it's still in its beta or pre-release phase.  Is it safe to start using it in spite of this or am I better off waiting for the official version 1.0 to avoid possibly breaking work I do in the mean time?

Comment: In my opinion, JQuery is not very stable. Even though, it's a beta, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: jQuery isn't stable? It's used on 45% of the top 10k most visited sites on the web. I think it's pretty safe.

Comment: @kennis, Yeah I haven't had any problems with jQuery stability at all!

Comment: @Michiel: Madness. jQuery is extremely stable.

Comment: I was talking about JQuery Mobile. For some reason, I thought it was about JQM... My apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an update.

Check http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

> Note: The jQuery team has decided not to take this plugin past beta. It is no longer being actively developed or maintained. The docs remain here for the time being (for reference) until a suitable replacement template plugin is ready.
>
> For more on the history of this change, see [Official Plugins: A Change in the Roadmap](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/04/16/official-plugins-a-change-in-the-roadmap/) and [jQuery Templates and JsViews: The Roadmap](http://www.borismoore.com/2011/10/jquery-templates-and-jsviews-roadmap.html).

And it seems to have another project as replacement.

> Note: A new template plugin fully supported by the jQuery Team is now being developed as part of jQuery UI. More details on the history of this can be found at http://blog.jquery.com/2011/04/16/official-plugins-a-change-in-the-roadmap/ and http://www.borismoore.com/2011/10/jquery-templates-and-jsviews-roadmap.html . Track progress and participate in the design at http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Template

Answer (score 1):

I've been using it pretty extensively for a couple large web apps and I love it. Definitely recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple philosophy when it comes to these types of questions.

I generally steer clear of anything beta for production systems.  However, having said that, if the V1.0 is due to release a few weeks before my software is due for release then I tend to weigh the odds.

If the Beta software has significant benefits to my application, or makes life easier then I go for it.  But the Beta software has to be in an acceptably stable state.  And like I said, it has to ship well before my application is due for release.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys! I think I'm going to go with griegs's answer on this one. I think I can put off the work I wanted to do for a little while. In the mean time, they'll probably release the official version of the templates plugin. Up 'til then, I don't want to get into the habit of using beta stuff for production.

Answer (score 1):

I've used it quite a bit and haven't had any problems.  Steve Sanderson uses them extensively as an integral part of [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) as well.

If you're still concerned though, I would recommend trying it out on smaller pieces of your project to see how it works out.